# Why am I getting an error saying that expressJwt is not a function?

Tags: javascript, jsx

So I am trying to implement this middleware in my code.

```
const expressJwt = require("express-jwt");

    function authJwt() {
      const secret = process.env.secret;
      return console.log(
        expressJwt({
          secret,
          algorithms: ["HS256"],
        })
      );
    }
    
    module.exports = authJwt;
```

But I am getting the following error - expressJwt is not a function

I have done npm install express-jwt. I do not understand why this is giving me this error.

[image: Error]

Comment: change it to this `const { expressjwt } = require("express-jwt")`

Comment: Did it and I am getting the same error

Comment: Ok so I did what you asked and now i am getting an error saying - TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function

Comment: You are exporting `authJwt`, but that function is not returning the result of the token signing, it is returning a `console.log`. If you tried to use this function as a Middleware, it's gonna fail. Try removing the `console.log` bit...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this..

```
const { expressjwt: expressJwt } = require('express-jwt');
```

Answer (score 5):

Your import statement might be formatted wrong. Try...

`const { expressjwt: jwt } = require("express-jwt");`

See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-jwt for more information.

---

UPDATE: anybody scrolling straight to this, see this comment for solvency => [Why am I getting an error saying that expressJwt is not a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71989118/why-am-i-getting-an-error-saying-that-expressjwt-is-not-a-function#comment127205110_71989118)

Comment: I am getting the error - TypeError: app.use() requires a middleware function after making this change

Comment: Did you add or edit the appropriate export expression?

Answer (score 1):

Your import statement might be formatted wrong. Try..

```
const {expressjwt:jwt} = require('express-jwt');
```

Then on your main file e.g index.js where you have your middleware, make sure you use this way:

```
app.use( '/protected', jwt({ secret: 'secret', algorithms['HS256'],}),
```

(request: { user: any; },response: { send: (arg0: string) => any; })=> {
if (request.user) return response.send(`Welcome, ${JSON.stringify(request.user)}`);
}
);

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```js
const { expressjwt: expressJwt } = require('express-jwt');
```

Then on your main file e.g app.js where you have your middleware, make sure you use this:

```js
app.use(**authJwt()**);
```