# express-jwt got TypeError: express_jwt__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2___default(...) is not a function

Tags: node.js, jwt, express-jwt

The following code works fine for express-jwt@5.3.1, but got TypeError for express-jwt@7.7.0

```
import expressJwt from 'express-jwt'

const requireSignin = expressJwt({ 
secret: config.jwtSecret, 
userProperty: 'auth',
algorithms: ["HS256"]
})
```

I am just start learning MERN, just don't know how to adapt this code to the latest express-jwt

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, just found the return type changed

Comment: It is a comment, not answer

Answer (score 0):

Relates to another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71989118/why-am-i-getting-an-error-saying-that-expressjwt-is-not-a-function#comment127205110_71989118)

Just need to tweak the way you import from

```
import expressJwt from 'express-jwt'
```

to the following as per official documentation

```
import { expressjwt } from "express-jwt"
```